# Ansible: Is there a way to look into a file, split the content in the file based on a specific criteria & then copy that content to another file?

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible & I've been trying to read the content of a file, split it based on a specific criteria & then I want to copy that content or return that content.

for example, a file sample.txt contains:

userid= "abc"

I want to read the content in sample.txt & split whereever there's a '=' sign, so that I can extract the creds (userid & abc) & then use it further.

I'm dropping drafts of the code snippets I've tried.

```
---

- name: extracting creds

  hosts: servers

  tasks:

    - name: read secure value

      lineinfile:

        path: /home/usr/Desktop/sample.txt

      register: creds

      debug:

        msg: "{{ creds.split('=') }}"
```

Another code I tried:

```
---

- name: Creds

  hosts: servers

  vars:

    test: /home/usr/Desktop/sample.txt

  tasks:

    - debug:

         msg: "{{lookup('file', test).split('=') }}"
```

None of them works :( What shall be followed to get it done?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following approach to read the contents from file and split them.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
  - name: add host
    add_host:
      hostname: "{{ server1 }}"
      groups: host1

- hosts: host1
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Fetch the sample file
    slurp:
      src: /tmp/sample.txt
    register: var1
  
  - name: extract content for matching pattern
    set_fact:
      sample_var1: "{{ var1['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall ('(.+=.+)', multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.split('=')[1] }}"
    loop: "{{ sample_var1 }}"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, it actually works, it splits up the content in the file. I don't have much idea in regex but yeah it solves the problem. :)

Comment: regex is very powerful feature for string operations. You may want to explore https://regex101.com/ how it works.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem could you please [consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @AnandaMuthiar Yeah, regex helps a lot but stuck at a point where I've to use AND, not entirely sure how to proceed on. I want to read each line and in whichever line it detects both "string" AND "=" sign, I want to split at that "=" to sign. Any suggestions how to proceed on?

Answer (score 1):

According to ansible doc, this is what `lineinfile` does. So, if you want to modify some content from one file and write to another file then this module wouldn't help.

> This module ensures a particular line is in a file, or replace an
> existing line using a back-referenced regular expression. This is
> primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file
> only.

`lookup` on the other hand works on control machine. Judging by the code you have added, may be you were trying to use the file on target host. So, lookup wouldn't help either.

If the file is available on local/control host then *read file, split content and copy to another file* on the control machine and then copy the final file to the target host using `copy` module. Here is a sample that reads a file from control host and split every line using `=` as a separator.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.split('=') }}"
      with_lines: "cat /home/usr/Desktop/sample.txt"
```

If the file is on remote/managed host then you can use something like below:

```yaml
- hosts: servers
  tasks:
    - command: "cat /home/usr/Desktop/sample.txt"
      register: content

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.split('=') }}"
      loop: "{{ content.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, I realized lineinfile & lookup won't work in this case. I tried your solution & for sure it works in local system. To make it work in target host, we may try some other way of doing it. slurp/ fetch can suffice the purpose of reading the file in target node.

Comment: Yes, earlier solution assumes the file is on local. Added a sample solution for file on remote.

Comment: Yes this works, command module executes commands on targets.